# Is there any open source npm package about authentication with oauth2 and openid connect to use in nativescritp

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, nativescript

After a lot of research i found one package from Oauth0 to authentication on nativescript mobile app - Auth0 Social Authentication Plugin for NativeScript.
I have my own Identity provider and i'm looking for any kind of source code or package to use with...

Anyone?

I don't wanted to ask it here, but i'm already did a question about it on reddit (https://redd.it/4kawea) and on nativescript's slack community too...

Comment: You can create your own plugin - anie how-to articles you can find at https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins and http://developer.telerik.com/featured/creating-nativescript-plugins-in-typescript/

Comment: I'm currently testing a framework that does not use DOM, that is browser-agnostic, [js-client-oauth2](https://github.com/mulesoft/js-client-oauth2). I'm impressed and after finish my tests i'll do that as a nativescript's plugin as you said.